# Pittosporum plants dying

Tags: plant-health

I live in San Francisco bay area (Fremont, hardiness zone 10b).
I have planted pittosporum tenuifolium as hedge plant. I have about 30 plants, these are growing very healthy for the last one year and are about 6' tall now. However in the last one month few of them dying (one died, one partially died, one started dying. See attached photos).
Any idea what could be the reason. I water them once a week and one died in fact near to lawn where lawn is watered twice week.,
I had gopher problems before, however I don't see any gopher activities in the last few months.
Any idea what could be the reason these plants dying?
Starting to Die
[image: Starting to die]
Partially dead
[image: Partially dead]
Dead
[image: Dead]

Comment: I meant to comment but it ended up as an answer (now deleted). Did you plant the hedge yourself? Do you know if the plants came in pots or in balls?